# Reading a list of lists into Python

Tags: python, list

I have made a list of lists to store score data for a given student. The list is called "class1" and each student has a name followed by 3 scores. I can sort this list fine and can write to a file which show the data in the correct format:

```
class1=[["Tom",7,2,1],["Jo",8,0,0],["Adelphe",9,0,0]]
```

When written look like this which I am happy with:

```
['Tom', 7, 2, 1]
['Jo', 8, 0, 0]
['Adelphe', 9, 0, 0]
```

The problem comes when I try to read the same list in. Each sublist is read as a string. I can't seem to change this.

Here is the code:

```
class1 = [line.strip() for line in open("data2.txt", 'r')]
```

This is what the list looks like when read, as you can see there are apostrophes around each sub list, meaning they are strings within the class1 list:

```
["['Tom', 7, 2, 1]", "['Jo', 8, 0, 0]", "['Adelphe', 9, 0, 0]"]
```

Can anyone help me, I've done a lot of searching, but can't find anyone with the same problem.

Thanks, Tom

Comment: You mean `split`, not `strip`.

Comment: Why not use JSON or CSV instead of inventing your own format?

Comment: Try using `eval(string)`. If the string represents a list, it should become a python list object. I.e. `class1 = [eval(line.strip()) for line in open("data2.txt", 'r')]`

Comment: Why not use namedtuple() ?

Comment: If the file you're writing to doesn't need to be human readable/editable, you can use the `pickle` module to write it and load it... will be more efficient that storing as text, then evaluating the input on reading again

Comment: Hi Wooble, I'm looking into CSV, I think this would be more appropriate. The script must take in a name and score, if the name exists in the list, then the latest score will be added, else a new name with score will be added to the list.

Comment: Note that using CSV, when you re-read the file, all elements will be string types again. If you want the types to survive the round trip, you're better off using JSON.

Comment: Would tuples work, I thought they couldn't be updated?

Comment: @Wooble would just a list entry with a single string be better, then use string methods to grab the data I need? I'm new to lists and this just seemed logical to me.

Comment: Hi @Jon, I will try pickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open('/path/to/data2.txt', 'r') as classes:
        lines = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in classes]

>>> print lines
[['Tom', 7, 2, 1], ['Jo', 8, 0, 0], ['Adelphe', 9, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Hi, eval worked. What is the benefit of using: ast.literal_eval? Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: @TomSmith `ast.literal_eval` protects against arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @TomSmith ```eval``` will evaluate **any** valid expression which makes it possible for *unknown* data to harm your computer, like creating a huge string and eating up your processor time and/or memory.  Unless you are 100% sure of your data don't use ```eval```, ```ast.literal_eval``` is safer because it restricts the types of expressions it will eveluate.

Comment: @wwii Note taken! Thanks

Comment: @TomSmith: `ast.literal_eval()` only supports save Python literals as input; strings, numbers, booleans, containers. Nothing more. `eval()` supports arbitrary Python expressions, including everything that a process can do to damage your computer or turn it into a subservient internet spam bot. It is for that reason I voted to delete the answer you marked as accepted; it is *dangerous* to use `eval()`, and you should avoid it for everything but the most specialised of cases where you are sure not to be executing user-supplied input.